# Image-hashing algorithm to produce natural primary-key values that work well in PostgreSQL table indices?

Tags: python, algorithm, postgresql, image-processing, hash

I'm building out a set of cooperative data stores with images, and I'm starting to implement some simple/trivial content-based search and sort algorithms: SIFT, sparse color-histogram distance, basic SVD, etc.

I am currently using sha1 hashes of binary data as indices in PostgreSQL tables. These hashes are 'dumb' -- they're calculated by feeding the data in question* straight to Python's `hashlib.sha1` module, and stored in nullable char columns that are exactly as long as the sha1's base64 representation.

It would be quite a panacea to implement a hash algorithm that would yield hashes suitable for indexing Postgres tables, but that also described the image in some way, à la [phash](http://phash.org/) or [hamming distance](http://pespmc1.vub.ac.be/ASC/Hammin_dista.html). While phash looks like a good candidate, it turns out to require the use of a proprietary storage engine and API... I'm looking for something less 'turn-key' that will play nice with my existing Python/Postgresql/Solr/Redis-based ecosystem.

It doesn't have to be the fastest -- it's more important for me to implement an algorithm (or algorithms) that can be hacked up a bit and stay somewhat cogent.

( * ) mostly this consists of untransformed or lightly transformed harvests from my images -- things like: JPEG/PNG/DNG image file content, ICC profile data structures, JSON dumps of EXIF/IPTC tagsets, and the like.

Comment: There is a conflict between how DB indexes work and the requirements for an image hash. DB indexes are one-dimensional (linearly ordered). Image similarity is modeled as a metric in a multidimensional space (at least I don't know any algorithm that would use anything weaker.) There is no distance-preserving mapping from the multidimensional space onto the linear index.

Comment: Aha -- Jitamaro's post (below) seems to suggest a space-filling curve as a means to single-dimensionality without a great deal of lossiness. Is that a possible end-run in this case? ... In any case, at the moment I'm pursuing statistical color analysis rather than feature-extraction; I'll definitely take a different approach with indexing tables full of extracted features as per your point -- but so if you're humoring me here for a moment: might there be a hash for color data (single-channel or otherwise) that could also work as a db index?... Either way, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm afraid even a single color is too much for a single dimension. We humans are trichromatic, which means that color similarity is 3D. You have to pick a single value - luminancy, variance thereof, or something similar. Not much hope for accuracy with this approach, though.

Comment: @Rafal: A space-filling-curve can reduce any dimension to 1 dimension. That's because a sfc has a fractal dimension. So a 3d curve is possible.

Comment: @Jitamaro: SFC doesn't really reduce the dimension of the similarity metric. OK, the 2D image becomes a 1D line but similarity of pixel lines is still multidimensional. With Hamming distance, there are as many dimensions as there are pixels in the line - two lines can differ independently on each of their `n` pixels.

Comment: @Rafal: I don't think you understand the concept of sfc or a fractal. A sfc it useful exactly because of the properties you fight.

Comment: Ok then, how do you transform the sfc into a value suitable for DB indexing, so that close values represent similar pictures?

Comment: @Rafal: A good start would be a single colour and a treemap or heatmap signature or fingerprint.

Comment: @Jitamaro: Please elaborate. How exactly do you want to use a SFC here?

Comment: You index the complete x,y skipping the coordinates that has a null value. Then you concatenate and md5 sum the index?

Comment: @Jitamaro I have seen some mention of sparse histograms w/r/t image hashing -- I'm using regular, vanilla 1d histograms of single-channel color data to calculate distance metrics but I'm not at the point of understanding how to sparsely tailor the histograms I'm working with ... regardless of that, though, the SFC idea is interesting enough that I'm going to look into it. I'm relatively confident that I won't come up with any sort of performant solution without some experimentation. Do either of you have any code examples of SFCs or other relevant techniques you could point me at?

Comment: @Rafal Is there anything one could accomplish by companding the (R,G,B) triplets into a single integer value -- i.e. the literal integer value a hex number like 0xFF1922 represents?

Comment: For 2d and 3d you can find a good solution at http://www.tiac.net/~sw/2008/10/Hilbert/. I've wrote a fast 2d php version for phpclasses.org (hilbert curve). I got the recipe from the hackers cookbook and from here http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves. The english wikipeda has some good code, too. But normaly you would start with writing a L-system and using a recursion.

Comment: @Jitamaro perfect, thanks for those links, I will proceed with those apace. Salud sir.

Comment: @fish2000: Depends on what you do with the numbers. If you just treat them as integers, then they're only OK for exact matches. Proximity metrics won't work too well. A small difference in the color that you put in the highest byte will cause a big difference in the integers compared as whole.

Comment: @Rafal aha of course, should have guessed that, thanks -- I'm also using solr, in the context of which this number may have more use. You don't happen to know if there is any way to extend PostgreSQL's native types with some kind of 'triplet' data type (either int or float) that would facilitate the storage and/or indexing of uncompanded color values?

Comment: @fish2000: Storage - yes. PostgreSQL lets you declare composite types.

Comment: Indexing - that's a tricky one. There's a GIS extension to PostreSQL that implements spatial indexing, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate for indexing colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a space-filling-curve, for example a hilbert curve or moore curve?

Comment: That's an interesting avenue of inquiry -- I have read a litte about hilbert curves, but I haven't put one to use. I'm assuming that I use the curve to flatten the image into a giant vector, upon which I can then apply a wide range of hashes and/or other transforms... Is that your suggestion?

Comment: Basically a hilbert curve is a tiling curve. It helps to reduce the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity but to transform it into a hash you will need another algorithm, maybe a fast fourier transformation. I wanted to suggest you something like the jpeg compression which uses a z-curve and a fast fourier transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Quite interesting approach is described in http://railsware.com/blog/2012/05/10/effective-similarity-search-in-postgresql/.

Basically image is scaled to 15x15 px, then intensity is calculated for each pixel (0.299 * red + 0,587 * green + 0,114 * blue). This array of 255 values is stored in PostgreSQL table column with Gin/Gist index for fast search of similar images.

Comment: That article is fascinating, and quite relevant – image-fingerprinting in PL/SQL is a domain-specific feat, indeed. Thank you!